# Discord.py || How to loop a part of Program infinite times without crashing it eventually?

Tags: python, loops, crash, python-asyncio, discord.py

I am Trying to Make a 24/7 Streaming Discord Bot using while(True): Infinite Loop,
But I think that the while(True): will get crashed by the OS (Using Heroku for Hosting) or Some kind of threads problem

```
@commands.command(name='play',aliases=["p"])
    async def _play(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        i = 0 
        while(True): #Infinite While Loop
            search = URL[i] #URL is the List of Musics I What to Stream 24/7
            if not ctx.voice_state.voice:
                await ctx.invoke(self._join) #joins the voice channel if not in voice channel previously

            async with ctx.typing():
                try:
                    source = await YTDLSource.create_source(ctx, search, loop=self.bot.loop)
                    #Sets the Status of the Bot to What Music it is Playing Currently
                    await self.bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name=f"{source.title}"))
                except YTDLError as e:
                    await ctx.send('An error occurred while processing this request: {}'.format(str(e)))
                else:
                    song = Song(source)
                    await ctx.voice_state.songs.put(song) #Enqueue the Song
            
            i = (i + 1) % len(URL) # Updates the Index of URL
            await asyncio.sleep(source.DURATION) #Gets the Lenght of the Music in int and Sleeps
```

I thought of using Asyncio Event Loops but Can't Figure it Out How to Use it Because my Function Has Parameters/Arguments like context (ctx)

I have Also thought of Cleaning the Memory stack after each songs play... But is it possible ??? If yes can we use it to fix my problem

**So Is there anyway to Loop The above Mentioned Block or Code Infinitely without crashing it eventually**

Thanks in advance !!!

*I have a Out of Topic Query... Can we Use the ability of **Context** (ctx) without passing it as a Argument.*
*If we Can then I might be able to use **asyncio_event_loop**, I suppose*

Comment: Quick thing first: make sure your indentation is correct. I'm sure it just copy+pasted weird, but just in case (also, it's 'while True:', not while(True) - not trying to be pedantic). Second, If I was making this function, I think it would make more sense to use conditionals triggered by start or stop of the song (with an error handler). Maybe a while loop for 'song_playing == True' or something similar. Is the infinite loop necessary?

Comment: I am Thinking of Playing a List of Songs 24/7 Like a Radio
I also have a URL[i] List with 150+ Songs Name
so the Bot will Play All these 150+ Songs One after another 24/7 Continiously
So I Guess I need a Infinite Loop Anyways, For this purpose

Comment: I understand your goal, I'm just wondering if the infinite loop is necessary for it. I apologize for not giving specific code, but I deleted my discord account some months ago and am a little rusty. But what I'm saying is that I think if you load your cog and trigger the radio function, you can start a song in a loop, then when the song ends have it retrigger the function recursively. That seems less resource intensive and prone to bugging out on you.

Comment: What about a List of Songs like
URL = ["a","b","c",...]
Then I Have to Take a Loop for iteration... I Think so. 
Is there any other way to iterate the URL. I have Understood that the While loop is Stacking up the Memory and Getting Crashed. I have to Somehow get Rid of This Memory Stacking..
Thanks for the Idea I will Think on it

Comment: If it helps at all, I recently learned that utilizing dictionaries takes less memory than lists (and might actually be easier to work with for your purposes). Probably not by much, but the more you know... But yes, the way python handles memory, it isn't going to clear out its stack until the loop collapses, which is why I suggest structuring your function something like: 1) start song/display song data 2) while song_playing == True: pass 3) iterate to next song (rand or sequential) 4) call function (goto 1). This makes sense in my head, but I can't test it for you.

Comment: I was just looking through old code, and you might want to read up on @tasks.loop. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/

Comment: Thanks For your help... This Might Actually Work... thanks
Now i Have to just iterate the URL which will take a lot less memory process as compair to my current codes

Comment: Glad it helped you. Bot coding can be tricky and counter-intuitive.